# How do I unlock the bootloader on the Samsung Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: bootloader, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have a LTE (Verizon) Samsung Galaxy Nexus. How do I go about unlocking the bootloader such that I can root the device?

Answer (score 6):

[Full instructions can be found here.](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/12/05/how-to-unlock-the-galaxy-nexus-bootloader/)

In short:

1. [Install SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
2. [Get the Fastboot.exe](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?9jkbuuu5z64ryy4) and place in your SDK/tools
3. Turn on USB debugging on phone
4. Connect to PC via USB
5. Using adb, run `adb reboot bootloader`
6. At the bootloader, run `fastboot oem unlock`
7. Accept dialog to unlock bootloader
8. Start phone, phone will reboot, **do not battery pull!**

[Afterwards, you can get root access.](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/12/15/how-to-root-the-galaxy-nexus-4g-lte-and-flash-custom-recovery-verizon/)